# GWT - Connect to talk.google.com from GWT Application

Tags: java, gwt, xmpp, google-talk

I want to connect to google server from my GWT Application, to integrate google chat into my Appllication.
I have tried using the emite gwt library, but haven't been successful with the configuration needed to connect to the google server.

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

I am getting the following exception when trying to use Emite in GWT application.

```
00:01:07.158 [INFO] Thu Jan 24 16:54:19 IST 2013 com.calclab.emite.core.client.bosh.XmppBoshConnection SEVERE: Connection error #1: Bad status: 302
```

In web.xml

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Proxy</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>de.spieleck.servlets.ProxyServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>remotePath</param-name>
    <param-value>/http-bind/</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>remoteServer</param-name>
    <param-value>talk.google.com</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>remotePort</param-name>
    <param-value>5222</param-value>
</init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Proxy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/http-bind</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In GWTModule.html

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="emite.httpBase" content="/http-bind">
<meta name="emite.host" content="talk.google.com">
<meta name="emite.session" content="login">
<meta name="emite.onBeforeUnload" content="logout">
<meta name="emite.user" content="abc@gmail.com">
<meta name="emite.password" content="xxxxx">
<meta name="emite.chat" content="xxxx@gmail.com">
```

What am I missing here?

Regards

Comment: 'haven't been successful'...  any exception ??

Comment: I am getting the following exception.

00:01:07.158 [INFO] Thu Jan 24 16:54:19 IST 2013 com.calclab.emite.core.client.bosh.XmppBoshConnection SEVERE: Connection error #1: Bad status: 302
remoteServer : talk.google.com
remotePort : 5222

Comment: Please attach code snippet and error log as starting point for other developers to help you.

Comment: what is the type of the request ???

Comment: @SSR Please find the snippet above. I need to know, how do I connect to talk.google.com using Emite Library.

Comment: @SSR - What do you mean my "request". Here I m trying to connect to google server using Emite.

Comment: I am using emite i my GWT Application. I have configured Ejabberd. Through emite library I can connect to admin@localhost from my application. I want to connect to gtalk server thorugh my application. I want to chat with gtalk user from my application.

Comment: Without your code I can only guess: you're using some library, that doesn't handle redirections.

Comment: I am using Emite library in my application following the example at
https://github.com/EmiteGWT/emite/tree/master/examples/src/main/java/com/calclab/emite/example/chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searches and tryouts - 
It seems that Google does not have their own bosh endpoint which would proxy request to google xmpp server.
So, somehow ProxyServlet isn't working for me to connect to google server.

But now I am able to connect to google server using `JabberHTTPBind`.
I used the `emite-0.4.7-proxies.jar`, which has `JabberHTTPBind` servlet bundled.
In web.xml, added the below servlet mapping

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jabber HTTP Binding Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jabber.JabberHTTPBind.JHBServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jabber HTTP Binding Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/http-bind/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

This worked for me. And now I am able to connect to google server using Emite.